# std::thread throwing Unhandled exception: Access violation reading location

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception, access-violation

I'm trying to get multi threading working on my simple server project. It was working fine on my laptop, yet when I moved the project folder to my desktop, it gives me an unhandled exception at my std::thread call.

I have a method StartAcceptingClients() which works fine when unthreaded and called on it's own. However when I call it by new thread:
std::thread clientsThread(StartAcceptingClients);
It throws:
Unhandled exception at 0x62E50BD0 in WinsockServer.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x62E50BD0.

MCVE:

```
#pragma once

#undef UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
// #pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

#include "Client.h"

WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult;

SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
struct addrinfo hints;

int iSendResult;
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

const int MAXUSERS = 8;
Client* clients[MAXUSERS];

void ListenForNewClient()
{
    //Listen to socket
    printf("Listening for connections...\n");
    iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        std::cin.get();
        return;// 1;
    }
}

Client* AcceptNewClient()
{
    // Accept a client socket
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        std::cin.get();
        return NULL;// 1;
    }
    Client* client = new Client(); client->socket = ClientSocket;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXUSERS; i++)
    {
        if (clients[i] == NULL)
        {
            clients[i] = client;
            clients[i]->clientID = i;
            printf("Client %i has joined.\n", i);
            break;
        }
    }

    // No longer need server socket
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    return client;
}

void StartRecievingFromClient(Client* client)
{
    // Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
    do {

        iResult = recv(client->socket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0) {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);

            // Echo the buffer back to the sender
            iSendResult = send(client->socket, recvbuf, iResult, 0);
            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(client->socket);
                WSACleanup();
                std::cin.get();
                return;// 1;
            }
            printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Client %i has disconnected.\n", client->clientID);
        else  {
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(client->socket);
            WSACleanup();
            std::cin.get();
            return;// 1;
        }

    } while (iResult > 0);
}

void StartAcceptingClients()
{
    ListenForNewClient();
    Client* client = AcceptNewClient();
    client->listenThread = new std::thread(StartRecievingFromClient, client);
}

//int __cdecl main(void)
int main()
{
    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        std::cin.get();
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        std::cin.get();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        std::cin.get();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        std::cin.get();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    std::thread clientsThread(StartAcceptingClients);

    printf("Game Loop Started.\n");
    //Game Loop
    while (true)
    {
        std::string Command;
        std::getline(std::cin, Command);
    }
    printf("Game Loop Ended.\n");

    // shutdown the connection since we're done
    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        std::cin.get();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It might be useful to see the implementations here. Are you able to provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example? See stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Done. Hope that's enough.

Comment: Is there no `join` or detach for `clientThread` ? is `clientThread` in a scope block that is left while still in main? (and, no, it isn't enough; the *complete* part of a MCVE is not met at all). I would think debugging this would be informative.

Comment: Time to fire up your debugger.

Comment: Ok I just edited in the entire server main.cpp code. The only thing missing is the Client class which just stores a socket, client ID, and a reference to that clients listen thread.

Comment: Please read the link which talks about a minimal but *complete* example.

Comment: This IS minimal and complete. Again, I'm trying to get the most simple form of a server to multi-thread listening to multiple clients with absolute MINIMAL code. This is my COMPLETE server code.